# excel formula parse string by LAST "\" and ".pdf"

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to parse a string for the last child node of a path using a formula?

Ie.

Stack\Over\Flow.pdf

parsing would get just "Flow".

`=mid(a1,find(":",a1)+1,len(a1))` I've tried this but I have to specify the name "Flow" , but if the strings change for each path, it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the last `\` we use

```
FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))
```

Now we use MID to return everything after that:

```
MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,99)
```

Then we substitute `.pdf` for a null string:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))))+1,99),".pdf","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott , not sure if this is worth asking a new question - If I want to add other things to substitute for null string, ie. I want to substitute .pdf for null and a 20180905 for null. how can I add a second parameter?

Comment: wrap in another substitute.  If it is always after the `.` then you can always use another find on the returned string and use Left.